# How do I clear/reset date field when using jquery datepicker

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using following code to display datepicker when a user clicks on textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="" class="mytextbox"></asp:TextBox>

$(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker();
    });
```

This is working fine but once user has selected a date, there is no way to clear that textbox as all keys are disabled.

I tried to use the following in that textbox but it doesn't work.

```
onkeypress="if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { $('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', null); }"
```

How do I clear the field?

Comment: Do you mind providing an example please? You can clear the value [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwhs6eso/). Is your input field disabled or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear a field all you would need to do is `$("#StartDate").val("");`

see comment below you can see a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrYro7oBllw2GMVNXW1E?p=preview)

Comment: But that's the question as to where to do I call this method? Because keyCode 8 and keyCode46 doesn't work. I tried to "alert" inside that code but nothing happened.

Comment: so to do this you would bind the event instead of adding it as an attribute. `$(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker().on("keydown",function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { $('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', null); }});
    });`  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrYro7oBllw2GMVNXW1E?p=preview)